# Laravel - Extend Model $guarded from parent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a `BaseModel` class which extends the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'company_id', 'identifier'];
}
```

In my other Model classes, I extend the `BaseModel`, and I am trying to extend `$guarded` from `BaseModel` in the child Models:

```
class Person extends BaseModel
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->guarded = array_merge($this->guarded, ['address', 'phone']); //This is that I'm trying to do
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Is it possible to extend `$guarded` from parent Model or I need to declare all fields on child models too?

**SOLUTION** - *Thanks to @Jignesh Joisar*!

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->guard(array_merge($this->getGuarded(), ['address', 'phone']));
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **GuardsAttributes** trait function already there on baseModel

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->guard(array_merge($this->getGuarded(), ['address', 'phone']));
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help, it worked now but just this way:
`
$person = new Person();
$person->fill($request->all());
`
but not work like this:
`
$person = new Person($request->all()); //this way it only keeps parent guarded
`
But I think it's the only way because it first calls the parent constructor and after changes the guarded with `$this->guard(...)`..

Comment: Update: I just changed the order on the constructor, first I call `$this->guard()` and then `parent::__construct()` and it worked! Thank you very much!